# JQuery collect group of elements, unwrap each and then wrap all in new element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to convert markup for a listing of businesses in which every line is a `<p>` and only the business name is also wrapped in `<strong>`. Instead I want each business' entire listing to be wrapped in one `<p>` and use `<br/>` to separate the lines.  Here is the original markup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <p><strong>Name of Business 1</strong></p>
   <p>Membership Level 1</p>
   <p>Name of Owner 1</p>
   <p>555 Someplace Ave 1</p>
   <p>Nowhere, OH 55555 1</p>
   <p>555-555-5555 1</p>
   <p><a href="mailto:test@test.com">test@test.com</a> 1</p>
   <p>Business Description 1</p>
   <p><strong>Name of Business 2</strong></p>
   <p>Membership Level 2</p>
   <p>Name of Owner 2</p>
   <p>555 Someplace Ave 2</p>
   <p>Nowhere, OH 55555 2</p>
   <p>555-555-5555 2</p>
   <p><a href="mailto:test@test.com">test@test.com</a> 2</p>
   <p>Business Description 2</p>
</div>
```

Here is what I need to change it to:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <p>
        <strong>Name of Business 1</strong><br>
        Membership Level 1<br>
        Name of Owner 1<br>
        555 Someplace Ave 1<br>
        Nowhere, OH 43021 1<br>
        555-555-5555 1<br>
        <a href="mailto:test@test.com">test@test.com</a> 1<br>
        Business Description 1<br>
    </p>
    <p>
        <strong>Name of Business 2</strong><br>
        Membership Level 2<br>
        Name of Owner 2<br>
        555 Someplace Ave 2<br>
        Nowhere, OH 43021 2<br>
        555-555-5555 2<br>
        <a href="mailto:test@test.com">test@test.com</a> 2<br>
        Business Description 2<br>
    </p>
</div>
```

I managed to get it done with some of the most ugly convoluted code ever.  Basically I took a step by step approach, as I just couldn't get any chained solution to work.

Here is that unfortunate solution:

```js
 jQuery('p > strong').parent('p').addClass('strong').has('br').addClass('clean');

 jQuery('p:not(.clean)').addClass('unwrap');
 
 jQuery('.unwrap.strong').nextUntil('.strong').each( function(){
  var theHTML = jQuery(this).html();
  jQuery(this).replaceWith('<span class="tomove">' + theHTML + '<br/></span>');
 });
 
 jQuery('span.tomove').each(function(){
  jQuery(this).appendTo( jQuery(this).prev('p.strong') );
 });
 
 jQuery('.unwrap strong').each(function(){
  var theHTML = jQuery(this).html();
  jQuery(this).replaceWith('<strong>' + theHTML + '</strong><br/>');
 });
 
 jQuery('span.tomove').replaceWith(function(){
  return jQuery(this).contents();
 });
 
 jQuery('p.strong.unwrap').addClass('clean').removeClass('unwrap');
```

```css
p {background:yellow}

strong {background:red;color:white;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
 <p><strong>Name of Business 1</strong></p>
 <p>Membership Level 1</p>
 <p>Name of Owner 1</p>
 <p>555 Someplace Ave 1</p>
 <p>Nowhere, OH 55555 1</p>
 <p>555-555-5555 1</p>
 <p><a href="mailto:test@test.com">test@test.com</a> 1</p>
 <p>Business Description 1</p>
 <p><strong>Name of Business 2</strong></p>
 <p>Membership Level 2</p>
 <p>Name of Owner 2</p>
 <p>555 Someplace Ave 2</p>
 <p>Nowhere, OH 55555 2</p>
 <p>555-555-5555 2</p>
 <p><a href="mailto:test@test.com">test@test.com</a> 2</p>
 <p>Business Description 2</p>
</div>
```

I imagine there is a way to process this in one chained command, but I kept getting tripped up trying to build the reference using `.nextUntil()` and/or `.add()` while trying to unwrap each `<p>` and add the `<br/>` within that chain before wrapping each group.

Can anyone provide a better solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with; it should work regardless of the number of businesses and data parameters can vary in lengths. It does require that the first 'p' element is contains a 'strong' element and no other data field other than business names have a strong element:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
 var businesses = [], bizIndex = -1;
 $('.wrapper > p').each(function(i){
     var html = $(this).html();
     if ($(this).find('strong').length) {
       bizIndex++;
       businesses.push([html]);
     }
     else {
         businesses[bizIndex].push(html);
     }

 });
 $('.wrapper').empty();

 $.each(businesses, function(i) {
     var business = businesses[i];
   $('.wrapper').append($('<p>').html(business.join('<br>')+'<br>'));
 });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2rz7jp4z/3/

Comment: The '$'s are throwing me off.  I'm on Wordpress and have to use jQuery() instead of $().  I've replaced all the '$' with 'jQuery'...but I don't know how that impacts that last function: `$.each(businesses...` becomes `jQuery.each(businesses...`  In any case, when I add this code, it fails.

Comment: Nevermind. I found the problem.  I must've hit my keyboard accidentally and inserted a wayward letter F inside one of the 'bizIndex' instances.  Sorry.  This works perfectly.  Far more elegant than mine, as expected.  Thanks.  I wish I had enough 'reputation' to upvote you.

Answer (score 0):

The following uses the Strong element as a divider.  The JSbin supplied adds them to a new div to show the before / after.

http://jsbin.com/soyelozemi/4/edit

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var insert = $('<div class="wrapper2"></div>');
  var tempHolder = $('<p></p>');
  jQuery('.wrapper p').each(function(index){
    jQuery(tempHolder).append($(this).html() + '<br/>');
    if(jQuery(this).next().find('strong').length || index == jQuery('.wrapper p').length-1){
      jQuery(insert).append(tempHolder);
      tempHolder = jQuery('<p></p>');
    }
  });
  jQuery('.after').append(jQuery(insert));
});
```

Comment: Turns out the list (hundreds of business long) does not always contain only 7 lines.  The only way to delineate where a grouping should begin is by looking for the `<strong>` tag.

Comment: Fixed my code to reflect this change.  This solution uses only 1 loop instead of 2.